# setTimeout with function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet to open links with specific text, but I'm facing a problem with the `setTimeout` portion ...

```
javascript:(function(){
    function clickLink(link) {
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
            event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            link.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else if (link.fireEvent) {
            link.fireEvent("onclick");
        }
    } 

    l=document.links;
    for(var i=0;i<l.length;++i) {
        var lL=l[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase(); 
        if(lL.indexOf("click here")!=-1 || lL.indexOf("how")!=-1) 
             setTimeout(function() {clickLink(l[i]) }, 1000);
        }
    }; 
})();
```

If I try `setTimeout(clickLink(l[i]), 1000);`, then it works, but it runs immediately rather than waiting for the timeout!

Also want to know one more thing that clicking links this way will fire mousedown/mouseup event? If not then how can I programmatically click links which will also fire mousedown/mouseup events?

Comment: looks like you're putting all that js into an `onclick` attribute of a link or a button. It might be easier for you to debug if you put it into a function and call that function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're coming across the usual "loop variable in a lambda" problem: by the time the timeout is done, `i` will be past the end of `document.links` and `l[i]` will be `undefined`. You could just wrap that part in a(nother) function:

```
(function(item) {
    setTimeout(function() { clickLink(item); }, 1000);
})(l[i]);
```

Comment: That solves the problem.. Thanks. BTW clicking links this way will fire mouseup/mousedown event?

Comment: @JamesSmith: No, it won't. You'll need separate events for those.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do that? I also need to fire the mousedown/mouseup events while clicking links by bookmarklet?